# What will be apple response if apple InApp purchase is pending?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, in-app-purchase

[image: InApp purchase pending in purchase history]

Please help me to know what will be the response when a user transaction is pending I am using SKpaymentDelegate methods

```
for (SKPaymentTransaction * transaction in transactions) {

    switch (transaction.transactionState)

    {

        case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:

            [self completeTransaction:transaction];

            break;

        case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:

            [self failedTransaction:transaction];

            break;

        case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:

            [self restoreTransaction:transaction];

        case SKPaymentTransactionStateDeferred:

            [self DefferedTransaction:transaction];

            break;

        case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchasing:

            [self PurchasingTransaction:transaction];

            break;

        default:

            break;

    }

};
```

What will the transaction state when purchase pending as shown in the screen short.